# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error de CORS con vue.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, api, cors

Estoy haciendo una petición de una API con `axios` desde `vuejs`, cuando consumí esta API desde el servidor me da una respuesta con status code, pero al intentar consumirla desde el componente vue me lanza un error:

> falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Este es el código:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
     <button v-on:click="fetch">Entrar</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'App',
   methods: {

    fetch() {


axios
     .get('https://...')
     .then(response => {console.log(response)
     }).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
   }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

¿Cómo puedo configurar mis headers en el vue?

Comment: Tu api está hecha en express?

Comment: Es una API de una empresa externa, y fue hecha en php si no estoy mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)** es un método de seguridad del lado del navegador, que al intentar acceder a una **API** desde un **ORIGIN** no permitido bloquea el request.

Por lo cual vas a tener que hacer 2 cosas:

1. Habilitar **[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)** del lado del backend *(Cambia dependiendo que utilices de server)*
2. Agregar cabeceras en el **request** al que quieras acceder:

Para ello lo que suelo hacer es crear una instancia con todas las configuraciones generales que quiero en los **request** y la reutilizo para consultar mis servicios.

```javascript
var axios = require("axios");

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
});

axiosInstance
  .get("https://api.backend.com/datos")
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

**¿Que es CORS?**

CORS es un mecanismo que permite solicitar recursos de una página web desde un dominio (servidor) diferente del que sirve el primer recurso que se ha servido.

En otras palabras, CORS se produce cuando tenemos nuestro cliente (A), consumimos una API a un servidor (B), pero el servidor (B) consume otro servicio a un servidor (C) produciendo un intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado (CORS).

**¿Por que obtengo este error en el navegador pero no en POSTMAN o el lenguaje backend?**

Esta limitante solo existe en los navegadores web por seguridad, postman y su lenguaje backend consumen el servicio web directamente, por lo cual no están sujetos a esta limitante.

**¿Como soluciono el problema?**

Algunas opciones disponibles:

**1)** Si usted tiene acceso al servidor backend que responde a la API debe agregar el header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` para proporcionar la respuesta.
Puede leer más sobre este header [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

**2)** Si usted no tiene acceso al servidor de la API existe un feo "hack" llamado `JSONP`(JSON con padding). Esto consiste en definir el tipo de dato enviado como `JSONP`.

La magia que hay por detrás es agregar el end point de la API dentro del atributo `src` de una etiqueta `script`, posteriormente este es agregando al DOM, obteniendo el contenido y luego removiendo la etiqueta.

Esto es posible ya que las etiquetas `script` no están limitadas a CORS, pero debe tener en cuenta que su petición siempre será `GET`, no podrá enviar `headers` personalizados y la respuesta del servidor siempre estará sujeta al formato de respuesta de `JSONP`.

**3)** En caso que no tenga acceso al servidor lo más recomendado es crear su propia API para consumir la API que desea, agregando así el `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Si tiene flojera de crear una simple API solo para consumir otra API puede buscar algún proyecto open source en GITHUB, hay varios desarrollados, usted no es el primer sujeto con este problema.

Comment: Axios no permite ocupar tu hack como solución

Comment: @FernandoTorres Axios no tiene soporte para Jsonp, pero si revisas su "libro de cocina" te recomiendan utilizar la libreria jsonp. [Enlace a un ejemplo practico en el repositorio de Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md#jsonp)